How can we ignore a specific component status - SpringBoot Actuator health
the /actutor/health endpoint in my application returns status for all the components in our app and the overall status. When a component is not available, it's status changes to DOWN and the overall status changes to DOWN as well.
Is it possible to exclude some components when determining the overall status? For example, if vault is not available, I want it's status to be reported as DOWN at the component level but I don't want the overall status to be DOWN (assuming vault is the only one down).
Just to be clear, I'm not looking to exclude vault component from /health endpoint completely. I still want to see the component included in the response, just not used for status aggregator.
I have looked at implementing a custom StatusAggregator but that doens't solve my problem.
{
"status": "UP",
"components": {
    "clientConfigServer": {
        "status": "UNKNOWN"
    },
    "discoveryComposite": {
        "status": "UP",
        "components": {
            "discoveryClient": {
                "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
                "status": "UNKNOWN"
            }
        }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "livenessState": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "mongo": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "ping": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "pubSub": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "readinessState": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "refreshScope": {
        "status": "UP"
    }
}

}
